# Derivative of squared derivative

Tags: calculus, physics

I'm reading Classical dynamics from Marion and Thornton, and in example 2.1 they solve the situation of a box moving down an inclined plane.

And the end of the exercise they have that:

$ \frac{dv}{dt} = g \sin(\theta) $

Now, they decide to find the velocity as a function of the displacement of the block and they do the following:

Multiply both sides by  $2 \frac{dx}{dt} $:

$ 2 \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dv}{dt} = 2 \frac{dx}{dt}g \sin(\theta) \tag{1}\label{1} $

$ \frac{d(\frac{dx}{dt}^2)}{dt} = 2 \frac{dx}{dt}g \sin(\theta) \tag{2}\label{2} $

And they proceed to remove $ dt $ and integrate both sides

It seems to me that they are doing a sort of chain rule from \eqref{1} to \eqref{2}:

$ \frac{d(\frac{dx}{dt}^2)}{dt} = 2\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d(\frac{dx}{dt})}{dt} = 2\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dv}{dt} $

But I don't understand the manipulation as both position and velocity can be derived with respect to time directly.

Comment: They can be. What’s the problem?

Comment: Going the reverse way seems easier for chain rule? $\frac{d}{dt} v^2$ = $2v \frac{dv}{dt}$ = $2\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dv}{dt} $

Comment: That's my issue, when deriving $ v^2 $, why are we adding later $ \frac{dv}{dt} $ again? I don't see why we have to apply the chain rule in this case. It's not like we have a function u that depends on y, and y depends on x, everything depends on time and can be derived directly. I wouldn't have passed from $ 2v $

Comment: We always apply the chain rule. Even when deriving $t^2$ w.r.t $t$, what is implicitly meant is $2t \frac{dt}{dt}$.

Comment: @Jon Your $v$ depends on $t$ (otherwise $\frac{dv}{dt} \equiv 0$ ) so you have $v^2(t)$.
Now differentiate w.r.t to $t$

Comment: Trying to understand the meaning of the overall calculation, it seems to me that the aim is to write a relation between v and x, without the time. From (2), by integration, you get something like $v^2=2 x g \sin(\theta)+C$, i.e. an equation without the time. It tells you the speed as a function of the position. This can be useful. Sorry if I did not get the point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always free to introduce more variables if it helps you.

For example, if $y = t^6, \frac{dy}{dt} = 6t^5$. But you can also say $u = t^2, y = u^3,$ and write $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dt}$$ which becomes $\frac{dy}{dt} = 3u^2\cdot 2t = 3t^4 \cdot 2t = 6t^5$, the same answer.  You have the option to do it in whichever way happens to be easier for you for a given problem.

In this one, they are essentially saying, "let's call $\frac{dx}{dt} = u$, so the left side is $u'$."  Then they multiply by $2u$ on both sides. By choosing $u$ as a derivative they are ensuring that they can integrate the right side, and on the left they have created $\frac{du^2}{dt}$.  It's a clever trick, I think.

Your chain rule is correct.

Comment: Thanks, your last paragraph helped me and I agree, looked clever to me as well. I think what it was confusing me is that is not $ \frac{dv^2}{dt} $ but $ \frac{d(\frac{dx}{dt}^2)}{dt} $ which as you say is a function that is a derivative. In this case, is u a function of x? Being the function a derivative on itself doesn't make it very clear

Comment: I think $v$ can be written as a function of $x$ in this case, via conservation of energy.  But in general, not necessarily.  Happy to help!